# Order post by date and custom meta

Tags: wordpress, meta

I have 2 custom meta one for the start date of my event and one for the end date of my event and I need to order my events according to the start date and to remove them when the end date is over.

Meta:

Start date: date_de_levenvement
End date: date_de_fin

Here is my loop:

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=agenda&meta_key=date_de_fin&meta_compare=>=&meta_value=' . $todaysDate . '&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
$date = get_field('date_de_fin');
$newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date)); ?>
```

Just need to change the query but I don't know how to use 2 parameters with the meta value. `&orderby=meta_value` needs to be something like `&orderby="date_de_levenement"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually use the more robust [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object to accomplish this task.  More specifically, you can see the section called [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) and see the example titled *Multiple Custom Field Handling*.  You can create your arguments array like so:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'agenda',
        'meta_key' => 'date_de_levenvement',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'date_de_fin',
                'value' => $todaysDate,
                'compare' => '>='
                )
            ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        );

$your_custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
if ( $your_custom_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $your_custom_query->have_posts() ) {
        $your_custom_query->the_post();
        // your code goes here
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Explanation**

The `meta_query` element is an *array of arrays* which means you can even filter against multiple meta (custom field) properties if you wish.  Notice that I included the `meta_key` element.  This is what will allow you to sort by your start date.  Whereas the `key` element of the `meta_query` element is what will filter your end date posts.  (In this situation, post types named `agenda` will only be included if their `date_de_fin` is greater than or equal to "today".

**[edit]**

Note that the "today" date should be formatted in SQL format like so:

```
<?php $todaysDate = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
```

Hope this helps a bit.  Have fun!

Comment: It doesn't not remove the date if the end date is yesterday for example !

Thanks :)

Comment: @jhon Upon initial look, I think the date format needs to be in SQL format for the compare to work.  I updated my answer with that clarification.

Comment: Nope, does not work... Take a look http://wordpress.yetix.be/ The date_de_levenement does not work. But the end date works well... and i use this $todaysDate = date('Y/m/d');

Comment: I'm using Jared's answer. I had to change 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', by 'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num',